# Get/target a document in an array inside another document mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this document schema in my collection:

```
_id: 631059faf95beef06e70a2bf,
cart:[{product_Id: "62be9f370d6b1ded3097e026",qty: 1},{product_Id: "62be9f370d6b1ded3097e027", qty: 1}],
username: "lucas@admin.com",
password: "$2b$10$YSQKuxr1tzV7SlSanj2N3eiUMVnO1fiJpvS5ka8g2UYSwFPvgg/I2",
alias: "lucas123",
avatar: "56fdfc0c-d6ca-461f-be85-80eb37144301.jpeg",
admin: true,
__v:0
```

What I need is to target the documents inside "cart" by the product_Id with mongoose, so I can update the qty and delete the target documents. Right now this is the code structure Im using to handle my queries:

```
addProduct(userId, productToAdd) {
  return this.db
    .then((_) =>
      this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        { $push: { cart: productToAdd } }
      )
    )
    .then((resp) => {
      return resp;
    });
}
```

The one above works fine, is just for you to know how my queries are strutured.

Thanks.

Comment: You basically need to increase a `qty` of a specific `cart` item (filtering by its `product_Id`). Correct?

Comment: @lpizzinidev Yes, that and be able to delete the target document by its product_Id

Comment: @lpizzinidev Thanks for your answer but cant find the way to make it work, I ended up solving it with JS but I still want to know how to do it with mongoose

    addQty(userId, productId) {
        return this.db.then( _ => this.model.findOne({ _id: userId }))
            .then( resp => {
                const index = resp.cart.findIndex( product => {
                    return product.product_Id === productId
                })
                if(index !== -1) {
                    resp.cart[index].qty += 1
                }
                return resp.save()
            })
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with JS, but I still want to know how to do it with mongoose:

```
addQty(userId, productId) { 
   return this.db.then( _ => this.model.findOne({ _id: userId })) 
   .then( resp => { 
       const index = resp.cart.findIndex( product => { 
           return product.product_Id === productId 
           }) 
           if(index !== -1) { 
               resp.cart[index].qty += 1 
           }

           return resp.save() 
})}
```

PD: Also didn't know if you resave something with the same _id Mongo replaces it and won't make a new document as I though it was.